# Is it possible to extend an Elixir protocol via `use/2` macro (for DRY)?

Tags: elixir

I have a project where I need to define a number of protocols with different names but having totally the same defines.

I've tried to do it with `use/2` but no luck: it doesn't work, defines from `__using__/1` don't appear in the resulting protocol:

```
defmodule Action do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      def run(tool)
    end
  end
end

defprotocol Actions.ShowId do
  use Action
end

defmodule Tools.SimpleRelay do
  defstruct [:id]

  defimpl Actions.ShowId do
    def run(%Tools.SimpleRelay{id: id}), do: IO.puts(inspect(id))
  end
end
```

On the struct with protocol implementation definition I get:

```
warning: module Actions.ShowId is not a behaviour (in module Actions.ShowId.Tools.SimpleRelay)
  iex:8: Actions.ShowId.Tools.SimpleRelay (module)
```

And if I try to use it:

```
iex(6)> relay = struct(Tools.SimpleRelay, id: "ALongStringId")
%Tools.SimpleRelay{id: "ALongStringId"}
iex(7)> Actions.ShowId.run(relay)
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Actions.ShowId.run/1 is undefined or private
    Actions.ShowId.run(%Tools.SimpleRelay{id: "ALongStringId"})
```

Is it a bug or a purpose? Or just my incorrect definition?

I've tried to ask the same question on [elixirforum](https://elixirforum.com/t/is-it-possible-to-use-use-2-macro-inside-defprotocol-block/30854) (and posted there this task background) and the only suggestion I got so far is that it is a bug. I would like to clarify it is really a bug before opening an issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Kernel.defprotocol/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#defprotocol/2) delegates to [`Protocol.__protocol__/2`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.10.3/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L4512-L4514) which in turn [redefines `def/2`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.10.3/lib/elixir/lib/protocol.ex#L678-L691) by unexporting `Kernel.def/2` and importing `Protocol.def/1` instead. In the context of your macro, `def` macro is referring to imported ATM `Kernel.def/2`, which breaks the desired behaviour.

I am not sure if this is a bug (error message could have been way more descriptive, though,) but you might easily overcome it by calling `Protocol.def/1` *explicitly*, using FQN.

```rb
defmodule Action do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
    # ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓  HERE
      Protocol.def(run(tool))
    end
  end
end

defprotocol Actions.ShowId do
  use Action
end

defmodule Tools.SimpleRelay do
  defstruct [:id]

  defimpl Actions.ShowId do
    def run(%Tools.SimpleRelay{id: id}), do: IO.puts(inspect(id))
  end
end
```

---

If you dislike how formatter handles parentheses around `Protocol.def/1`, feel free to delegate it to some local `defp/1` or something *and* amend your `.formatter.exs` with

```erlang
[
  inputs: ["{mix,.formatter}.exs", "{config,lib,test}/**/*.{ex,exs}"],
  locals_without_parens: [:defp]
]
```